# Using helper to turn an image to a link, but why isn't the link going where i pointed it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
  <td><%=    link_to(image_tag product_feature.photo.url(:thumb),{:action => 'edit', :id => product_feature.id})  %></td>
```

This is the  code that is in my view, but when ever i go to test the link, it keeps sending me to :action => 'list'.   Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need some parentheses, all your arguments are being passed to `image_tag` right now and that's probably not what you want:

```
<td><%= link_to(image_tag(product_feature.photo.url(:thumb)), {:action => 'edit', :id => product_feature.id}) %></td>
```